# Having trouble connecting to Joomla database for custom update function

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, joomla

Here is the code snippet that is giving me some trouble:

```
if ($accountMask){
function updateAccountMask(){

$userIdValue =& JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $userIdValue->id;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Fields to update.
$fields = $db->quoteName('cb_accountmask');

// Conditions for which records should be updated.
$conditions = $db->quoteName('user_id') . '='.$userId;

$query->update($db->quoteName('#__comprofiler'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->query();

return $result;

}

updateAccountMask();

}
```

I imagine that there is some simple formatting issue with the way I am building the database query, but it is not apparent to me at this time.  Any thoughts?

---

I found that the database connection is fine, the issue seems to be that I cannot pull the `$accountMask;` value inside the `updateAccountMask` function.  If I do the following:

```
if ($accountMask){
echo $accountMask;
function updateAccountMask(){
```

Then I can see the value echoed on the screen.  If I move this like so...

```
if ($accountMask){
function updateAccountMask(){
echo $accountMask;
```

no value shows up.

hmmm... why is that?

---

well this is just getting ridiculous...

I have tried so many combinations of trying to get the variable within the functions scope, but still no luck.  Here is the most direct method I recently attempted:

```
$accountMask = 'testing';   

if ($accountMask){
function updateAccountMask(){

    global $accountMask;
    echo 'Account Mask= ' . $accountMask;
```

Still, all I get output is `Account Mask=`.  What gives?!?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Lodder no errors are displayed, it just is not updating the field when it should.

Comment: If you use `echo $query->dump();` what does it display?

Comment: @Lodder UPDATE `#__comprofiler`
SET `cb_accountmask`
WHERE `user_id`=577

Comment: @Lodder okay... I think I see the issue.  It is connecting from that `dump()` command output, but it does not know what to do.  Ultimately I want the `cb_accountmask` value to be updated to equal the `$accountMask`.  How should I modify the `$fields` statement to achieve this?

Comment: You need to create $accountMask INSIDE the function. .  Why are you doing that as a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
// Change "varname" to the name of the input field
$accountMask = $input->post->get('varname');

if ($accountMask)
{
    self::updateAccountMask($accountMask);
}

function updateAccountMask($accountMask)
{
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $userId = $user->id;

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();    
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $fields = array(
            $db->quoteName('cb_accountmask') . ' = ' . $db->quote($accountMask);
        );

        $conditions = array(
            $db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = ' . $userId;
        );

        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__comprofiler'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->execute(); 

        return $result;    // I'm not sure what you are returning here ... i would just return true on success, exception or false on error
    }
```

One thing is you should probably be doing some more checking such as what if there is no such user.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I am getting the following error when implementing this code `Fatal error: Call to undefined method getupdateauthorizenetTab::updateAccountMask()`

Comment: ok, got it.  There are a couple of syntax errors in your answer, but I worked them out.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit the post to fix please or let me know and I'll fix.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you're basically not setting a value to be added into the database table. This is what it should look like:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
// Change "varname" to the name of the input field
$accountMask = $input->post->get('varname');

if ($accountMask){

    function updateAccountMask(){

        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $userId = $user->id;

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $fields = array(
            $db->quoteName('cb_accountmask') . ' = ' .$accountMask
        );
        $conditions = array(
            $db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = ' . $userId
        );

        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__comprofiler'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->query();

        return $result;

    }

    updateAccountMask();

}
```

As you can see, I have used `$db->quoteName('cb_accountmask') . ' = ' .$accountMask` so now the value is being set.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this and the `$accountMask` value does not seem to pull through.  I have explained this in greater detail in the question update.

Comment: Is the account mark value coming from an input field that a user types in? If not, where is it coming from?

Comment: the value is created by a form submission.

Comment: ultimately it looks like I am having some issue with the variable scope.  I have attempted setting the variable as `global $accountMask;` within the function, but still no luck.

Comment: @Presto - see the updated code at the top of my answer

Comment: I have attempted the input suggestion with no luck.  See my most recent question update as I have been pretty direct about defining the variable, but it still is not showing up.

Comment: How are you expecting $accountMask to be available inside the method?

Comment: @Elin I tried setting the variable as global inside the function, but that is not working.